# ajax response into a dialog window doesnt show changed value on 2nd attempt

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form that when the user clicks submit, fires off an php script via ajax to do validation.  right now the only thing it does is echo the post value.  if a user enters the word "Dog" into formEntry, the ajax response is Dog.  If a user cancels the dialog window, and then changes "Dog" to "Cat", the ajax response still shows dog.

```
 var dataToSend = "";
 var formEntry = $('#formEntry').val();   
 dataToSend += "data="+formEntry;

   $.ajax({  
               type: "POST",  
               url: "checkData.php",
               data: dataToSend,
               success: function(result){

    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    $('#dialog').html(result);
                            }
    });
```

the form entry:

```
 <div class='inputText'><input type='text' name='formEntry' id='formEntry' value='<?php echo $someValue;?>'></div>
```

as a test, i added alert(formEntry) right after the var definition, and it too displays "Dog". Even if i were to change the value multiple times, the value is always the first value of the ajax call.

Comment: Did you check what is coming back from the server?

Comment: alert(result)  shows the original entry as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
 dataToSend += was just adding more data to itself. addding:

 dataToSend = "";  at the beginning of the function solved the problem.
```

Comment: Posting the full code in the future would have shown this error. Look into jQuery's searlize()